# Check the answer to a math puzzle covertly?

Tags: android-studio, math, flutter, dart, routes

I am creating a math puzzle messenger game.

In the first row the sender types the actual math puzzle
In the second row the sender is supposed to write the the answer to that puzzle.

But he is not supposed to be allowed to type in the wrong answer to that puzzle.

How can I set the parameters, so that the app checks the set answer before sending the puzzle to the recipient?

https://github.com/wileecoyote2point0/math_game
[image]

Comment: What type of math puzzle are we talking about addition, subtraction or algebraic expression as well?

Comment: If the system can check whether the answer is correct, then why the user has to input the answer?

Comment: I want it to also include algebraic equations. As to the second question, I don't want anyone to send puzzles that they can not answer them selves. But I will include a way for the sender to find the answer, if they after a number of tries, still can't type the correct answer to their own puzzle.